# Yii2 ActiveRecord when first table updated or add new record, update second table column which is sum of first table column

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

So my goal is update table column which sum of another table column 
This is my beforeSave method in the first model `(Consumption)` :

```
public function beforeSave($insert){
        Accounts::updateAccount($this->user_id);
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
```

And In the Accounts model Accounts model updateAccount function:

```
public static function updateAccount($user_id){
        $account=self::find()->where(["user_id"=>$user_id])->one();
        if(!$account){
                $account=new Accounts();
                $account->user_id=$user_id;
                $account->default_currency=Currency::getDefault()->id;
                $account->value=0;
                $account->code=Accounts::getAutoCode();
                $account->created=time();
                $account->status=1;
                $account->save();
        }
        $sum=Consumption::find()->where(["user_id"=>$user_id])->sum("value");
        $account->value=$sum;
        $account->save();
    }
```

This function if condition works(id account not yet, it create new one for this user). But after `$account->value=$sum; $account->save();` doesn't save, any errors.
My validation rule for Accounts model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id', 'default_currency', 'value', 'status','code'], 'required'],
            [['created', 'user_id', 'default_currency', 'status',], 'integer'],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be an Account validation problem try with

```
    $sum=Consumption::find()->where(["user_id"=>$user_id])->sum("value");
    $account->value=$sum;
    $account->save(false);
```

if with the param set to false the account si saved then check selectively your Account validation rules and provide to review the rules or the application logic properly

Comment: Yeah u right.It it work now. Thanks @scaisEdge. There was validation errors. I fixed it ,now works properly